# what does "Fatal Assertion 18750" mean?

Tags: mongodb

In my mongodb replicaSet, I found one of the secondary node is down, and when I check the db.log, I found this:

```
I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] repl: old cursor isDead, will initiate a new one
I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: primary-node-ip:portNum
I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to primary-node-ip:portNum
I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] replSet our last op time fetched: Nov 25 05:41:01:85
I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] replset source's GTE: Nov 25 05:41:02:1
F REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] replSet need to rollback, but in inconsistent state
I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] minvalid: 5a1891f0:187 our last optime: 5a1891ed:28
I -        [rsBackgroundSync] Fatal Assertion 18750
I -        [rsBackgroundSync]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I googled, but don't really find any page to get this 18750 fatal assertion thing clearly.
the mongoDB version is 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say the MongoDB version you're using, but that particular assertion can be traced back to MongoDB 3.0 series.

Particularly, the cause of the assertion is printed in the logs you posted:

```
F REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] replSet need to rollback, but in inconsistent state
```

This message was printed by this part of the source code: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.0/src/mongo/db/repl/rs_rollback.cpp#L837-L841

What that message means is that the node needs to perform a rollback, but it discovered that it is unable to do so because it is in an inconsistent state (e.g. no rollback can be performed).

One possible cause of this issue is unreliable network connection between the replica set and the application, and also between the replica set nodes themselves, although the exact cause may be different between one deployment and another.

Please see [Rollbacks During Replica Set Failover](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) for more information regarding rollbacks.

Unfortunately there's not much that can be done in this case except doing a resync process of the asserting node. Please see [Resync a Member of a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) for details on how to do so.